# Implementing a last_login or last_active in laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a web app running on Laravel php 5.2
To check my user's activity and returning users, I have implemented a last_login field in my users table and a listener that will update it at every login.

All is good, but what happens is I have a 'remember me' token, and when the user has already logged in, and returns to the application with the token, the last_login is not updated.

I thought on updating this field on every user action, but it seems not so optimized, and will cause some performance issues. Any ideas on how I could implement this 'last_active' thing, having little impact on performance

Comment: Not getting your  `'remember me' token` part.Could please explore more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you suggest yourself, I would (and do) update a last active timestamp with every pageload/and ajax calls that affect a User ... You will need to be talking about millions of concurrent users for it to be an issue... but then you'd be into the arena of load balancing Web and DB serevrs anyway.

If you're idea of a high load is, hundreds or even thousands of concurrent users, updating a timestamp will have little impact, just make sure the user table is kept simple and well sensibly indexed.

Also, another good way to keep this in good shape (depending on you're architecture) is using 2 connections ... one for read-only queries and one for updates, inserts etc.